# setting a class property in extjs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use extjs to enhance my application. I used Ext.form.DateField for rendering the data in jsp. I use 'applyTo' property inside the dataField and render it in my jsp using its ID. my problem now is that I could not apply a specific class property(say width,height n color) to the text field, where I render the datefield. please help me out. Here is my sample code for your review.

thanks in advance.

regards,
Shalini.A

<----createTask.jsp----->

THIS IS THE EXT PART:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var custWindowEndDate =  new Ext.form.DateField({
    allowBlank:false,
    applyTo : 'oneTimeDiv', //apply to
    name: 'oneTimeDivDate',
    id : 'oneTimeDivDate',
    format:'m/d/Y g:i A',
    //fieldBodyCls: 'height-18_width-133 input_LegendsColor',
    Cls:'height-18_width-133 input_LegendsColor',
    width:150,
menu: new DatetimeMenu(),
    selectOnFocus:false
});
```

AND THIS IS THE HTML PART:

```
<div id="frequencySelection" class="dynamic-side-note-container">
<div class="maincontentleftcolumnHeaderBg_normal">
    <div class="sub_tool_accord_norm"></div>

    <div class="header_txt">Task Selection</div>
</div>

<div id="panel" class="side-note dynamic-side-note">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0"
       class="bodytxt">
<tr height="24">
    <td class="bodytxt" width="20%">
        <input type="radio" checked="true" value="rbOneTimeTask"
               name="rbOneTimeTask" id="rbOneTimeTask"
               tabindex="3"
               onClick="taskSelection(this); ">
        One Time Task on
    </td>

<td width="75%" colspan="4">
<core:bind path="createSchedule.txtOneDate">
<c:if test="${status.error}">

<script>displayAlert("${status.errorMessage}")</script>
</c:if></core:bind>
 <input type="text" name="oneTimeDiv" id="oneTimeDiv"  class="height-18_width-133 input_LegendsColor"  >
 </td>
</tr>
```